# How to allow access to wordpress plugin php file on a multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, stripe-payments

so I'm having an issue with a stripe payment form on a multisite, it gives me a 403 error in the console when trying to access a php file.

The file location is:
/wp-content/plugins/reservation/stripe/public/stripe-key.php

I've edited the htaccess file to include the following, but it crashes the site:

```
<Directory 'wp-content/plugins/reservation/stripe/public/'>
Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

After a bit of googling it seems I needed to use the full path name to the folder, using the following code I got the absolute path of the site:

```
<?php echo getcwd(); ?>
```

This spat out the following: (edited for security)

```
/home/000000.cloudwaysapps.com/aaaaaaaaaa/public_html/
```

But changing the htaccess file to include the following still crashes the website:

```
<Directory '/home/000000.cloudwaysapps.com/aaaaaaaaaa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/reservation/stripe/public/'>
Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

This is the first time I've needed to set permissions on a specific file using htaccess, so I have no idea if what I'm doing will work, if this isn't how to solve the issue then any other solution or any pointers in general would be extremely grateful.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: _“it gives me a 403 error in the console when trying to access a php file”_ - and what does the error log on the server have to say about that?

Comment: The error it gives me says "<Directory not allowed here", which after googling I found that I can't use directory in htaccess. So I need to point to that specific file to allow access but I'm not able to use directory to point to the path and right now I don't know of any alternatives.

Comment: I meant what the error log has to say regarding the original 403 error.